# Tika parser to parse contents of word/pdf

Tags: java, pdf, docx, apache-tika

I am interested in parsing MS Word document and pdf contents into contents and its structure. I should be able to roughly rebuild document from its contents.What tika methods would be used to obtain Header, footer, Heading 1, Heading 2,Table structure, Paragraph etc.

I have searched online for solution and I can not find accurate answers. Some of them are referring to Apache POI project. can someone suggest code to add to the following program-

```
public class MSWordParser {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, TikaException, SAXException, OpenXML4JException, XmlException {
        BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(new File("Sample_document.docx"));
        ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext();
        OOXMLParser msofficeparser = new OOXMLParser ();
        msofficeparser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata, pcontext);
        System.out.println("Contents of the document:" + handler.toString());
        System.out.println(" " + metadata.get(Metadata.CONTENT_TYPE));
        System.out.println("Sample Word Document"+ metadata.get(TikaCoreProperties.TITLE));
        System.out.println("Metadata of the document:");
        String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();

        for(String name : metadataNames) {
            System.out.println(name + ": " + metadata.get(name));
        }
```

Comment: Are the PDF files being produced from MS-Word? Apache Tika uses [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/), which, in turn, works best if the PDF are produced using the Office Guildelines for creating [Accessble/Tagged PDF's](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Create-accessible-PDFs-064625e0-56ea-4e16-ad71-3aa33bb4b7ed)

Comment: Did you try following the [Apache Tika example / tutorial on parsing documents to XHTML](http://tika.apache.org/1.10/examples.html#Parsing_to_XHTML)? You'll need to fetch as HTML not Plain Text if you want the document structure

Comment: Yes thanks for the help. I tried using ContentHandler handler = new ToXMLContentHandler() and it is now sowing output with html tags.